# Strip non-digit characters from data file in R

Tags: r

I have data in a .csv file where each entry includes surrounding text, like so:

Age
Quantity[19, "Years"]
Quantity[33, "Years"]
Quantity[20, "Years"]
Quantity[21, "Years"]
Quantity[18, "Years"]

BWT
Quantity[2622, "Grams"]
Quantity[2600, "Grams"]
Quantity[2594, "Grams"]
Quantity[2557, "Grams"]
Quantity[2551, "Grams"]

Running, e.g. lm(BWT ~ Age) in R generates this:

Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors.

Is there a way to modify the data file to strip the text so R doesn't interpret the data as categorical? Or is there some other way indicate to R that the data is numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your answer correctly, you have two variables, each of which are text strings that have numbers in them. You want to extract the numbers to use them in a regression. There's two steps here:
 - From the character string, pull out the substring that is just the numbers
 - Convert those numbers from "character" data type to "numeric" data type

For the first step -- text manipulation -- R has a great package, [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html), that you should check out.

For the second step, you use the `as.numeric` function.

In the example you shared, the following should work:

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_match(Age,"[0-9]+"))
```